# Docusign : One or both of Username and Password are invalid

Tags: docusignapi

I was testing Docusign PHP API and trying the following code:

```
$envelopeId = '3e979aac-1d8d-4ab9-rand-envelopid';

    $api = new APIService();
    $api->setCredentials('devaccountemail', 'devaccountpassword');

    $userName = 'Test Signer';
    $userEmail = 'random@randor.com';
    $userId = '457';

    $RequestRecipientTokenParams = new RequestRecipientToken();
    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->EnvelopeID = $envelopeId;
    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->Username = $userName;
    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->Email = $userEmail;
    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->ClientUserID = $userId;

    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->AuthenticationAssertion->AssertionID = rand(0, 999);
    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->AuthenticationAssertion->AuthenticationInstant = date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".date("d")."T00:00:00.00";
    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->AuthenticationAssertion->AuthenticationMethod = RequestRecipientTokenAuthenticationAssertionAuthenticationMethod::Email;
    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->AuthenticationAssertion->SecurityDomain = "local IP Address";


    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->ClientURLs->OnAccessCodeFailed = "https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&event=OnAccessCodeFailed";
    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->ClientURLs->OnCancel = "https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&event=OnCancel";
    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->ClientURLs->OnDecline = "https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&event=OnDecline";
    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->ClientURLs->OnException = "https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&event=OnException";
    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->ClientURLs->OnFaxPending = "https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&event=OnFaxPending";
    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->ClientURLs->OnIdCheckFailed = "https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&event=OnIdCheckFailed";
    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->ClientURLs->OnSessionTimeout ="https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&event=OnSessionTimeout";
    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->ClientURLs->OnSigningComplete = "https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&event=OnSigningComplete";
    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->ClientURLs->OnTTLExpired = "https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&event=OnTTLExpired";
    $RequestRecipientTokenParams->ClientURLs->OnViewingComplete = "https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&event=OnViewingComplete";

    $RequestRecipientTokenResponse = $api->RequestRecipientToken($RequestRecipientTokenParams);
```

I got the following Error:

```
SoapFault : One or both of Username and Password are invalid.
```

The credentials provided by me are valid and I can login to demo.docusign.net account with these credentials. I'm not sure where I'm doing it wrong.

Here is the SOAP request that is being generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-
     ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0" 
     xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
         <SOAP-ENV:Header>
            <wsa:Action>http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/RequestRecipientToken</wsa:Action>
            <wsa:To>https://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/api.asmx</wsa:To>
            <wsa:MessageID>uudi:638fd49c-2516-12a9-8159-17a9c602975e</wsa:MessageID>
            <wsa:ReplyTo>
                <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
            </wsa:ReplyTo>
            <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
                <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                    <wsu:Created>2013-09-18T12:30:20Z</wsu:Created>
                    <wsu:Expires>2013-09-18T12:35:20Z</wsu:Expires>
                </wsu:Timestamp>
                <wsse:UsernameToken>
                    <wsse:Username>bhargav.bonu@somedomain.com</wsse:Username>
                    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-
         token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">mypassword</wsse:Password>
                    <wsse:Nonce>0PZkAUVbHHiyjV8KZrN6x2x0S6cQ5WbAjTH4yn8dnc4=</wsse:Nonce>
                    <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-
         utility-1.0.xsd">2013-09-18T12:29:18Z</wsu:Created>
                </wsse:UsernameToken>
            </wsse:Security>
        </SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
            <ns1:RequestRecipientToken>
            <ns1:EnvelopeID>3e979aac-1d8d-4ab9-a45c-randElem</ns1:EnvelopeID>
            <ns1:Username>Test Signer</ns1:Username>
            <ns1:Email>Guest</ns1:Email>
            <ns1:AuthenticationAssertion>
                <ns1:AssertionID>175</ns1:AssertionID>
                <ns1:AuthenticationInstant>2013-09-18T00:00:00.00</ns1:AuthenticationInstant>
                <ns1:AuthenticationMethod>Email</ns1:AuthenticationMethod>
                <ns1:SecurityDomain>192.168.0.43</ns1:SecurityDomain></ns1:AuthenticationAssertion>
                <ns1:ClientURLs>
                    <ns1:OnSigningComplete>https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&amp;event=OnSigningComplete</ns1:OnSigningComplete>
                    <ns1:OnViewingComplete>https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?
         envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&amp;event=OnViewingComplete</ns1:OnViewingComplete>
                    <ns1:OnCancel>https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&amp;event=OnCancel</ns1:OnCancel>
                    <ns1:OnDecline>https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&amp;event=OnDecline</ns1:OnDecline>
                    <ns1:OnSessionTimeout>https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&amp;event=OnSessionTimeout</ns1:OnSessionTimeout>
                    <ns1:OnTTLExpired>https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&amp;event=OnTTLExpired</ns1:OnTTLExpired>
                    <ns1:OnException>https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&amp;event=OnException</ns1:OnException>
                    <ns1:OnAccessCodeFailed>https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&amp;event=OnAccessCodeFailed</ns1:OnAccessCodeFailed>
                    <ns1:OnIdCheckFailed>https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&amp;event=OnIdCheckFailed</ns1:OnIdCheckFailed>
                    <ns1:OnFaxPending>https://YourApp.com/DocuSignCallback.html?envelopeId=YourEnvelopeId&amp;event=OnFaxPending</ns1:OnFaxPending>
                </ns1:ClientURLs>
            </ns1:RequestRecipientToken>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 3):

That error indicates that the DocuSign user credentials you're providing in the request to authenticate the API call are not valid. The code you included in this post is irrelevant, really, as any API call would result in this error if either the username or password you're providing to authenticate the request is invalid.

If you haven't already done so, I'd suggest that you produce a trace of the full XML Request (i.e., including headers) to closely examine the authentication credentials that you're providing in the request. The best way to troubleshoot issues like this is to examine what's going over the wire (rather than trying to troubleshoot code that's producing what's going over the wire) -- once the issue in the XML is identified, it should be easy to fix in the code.

Comment: I've posted the SOAP request that is being generated. Will it be of any help?

Comment: Shouldn't be related to the "username or password invalid" error, but -- I notice that your request XML is missing <ClientUserID> -- this is a required element in the RequestRecipientToken request.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "username or password invalid" error -- it might be caused by the fact that your not including your Integrator Key within Username.  From page 18 of the DocuSign SOAP API Guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSignAPI_Guide.pdf):

The integrator key must be placed in front of the user ID that is in the Username node of the UsernameToken. The integrator key must be wrapped with brackets, “[ and ]”. Example format:

```
<wsse:Username>[Integrator Key]2988541c-4ec7-4245-b520-f2d324062ca3</wsse:Username>
```

The Integrator Key must be included in all API requests, as DocuSign requires it in order to identify the integrating application.

Comment: This was the solution in my case.
The username must be in the format "[IntegratorKey]Username".